# How to get number of products with 5 stars rating in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

How to get the number of products with 5 stars rating in woocommerce ?
I have tried this code but it is not working:

```
$products = get_posts(array(
 'post_type'   => 'product',
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'meta_query'  => array( array(
 'key'     => 'rating',
 'value' => '5',
 'compare' => '=',
  )),
));
```

Comment: // Get products with all 5-star ratings.
$args = array(
    'average_rating' => 5.0,
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
reference - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check WooCommerce [wc_get_products](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query) function documentation. it has an `average_rating` param.

If you don't want to use `wp_get_products` and then the correct meta key name for rating is `_wc_average_rating`

Comment: Thanks Mr. Vijay for your answer, I have tried _wc_average_rating and average_rating meta keys with wp_query but still not working, The query result always equal 0

Comment: Please edit your question and update what next things you tried and the code did you use so that it can be reviewed, tested &fixed by answerers.